# can not connect to infura service in web3.js?

Tags: web3js

i am working on the web3 1.0.0 -beta.36

my code is simple, to connect to infura service and fetch a transaction.

```
let rpcUrl = "https://mainnet.infura.io/ocCdekUYwOyLn7h7OlJM";
      var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(rpcUrl));
      web3.eth.getTransaction("0xaf7bfec2f84b35a58e93ebdf688ba079721b2ac064d7adff520100352206472d")
          .then(txObj => {
            console.log( txObj); // logs "string"
        });

[sm]:1 ERROR Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node https://mainnet.infura.io/ocCdekUYwOyLn7h7OlJM.
    at Object.InvalidConnection (errors.js:31)
    at HttpProvider.send (httpprovider.js:94)
```

Why i could not connect the infura service?

Answer (score 4):

Looks good to me:

https://jsfiddle.net/m3afvn0c/

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/ethereum/web3.js/1.0/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  let rpcUrl = "https://mainnet.infura.io/ocCdekUYwOyLn7h7OlJM";
  var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(rpcUrl));

  web3.eth.getTransaction("0xaf7bfec2f84b35a58e93ebdf688ba079721b2ac064d7adff520100352206472d")
    .then(txObj => {
    console.log( txObj); // logs "string"
  });
</script>
```

Output in console:

```
blockHash: "0x5e937a40e6213f2e27ef193e454c2dac67d487591df6bbf4fd7b4c6fbb1d1042"
​
blockNumber: 6375283
​
from: "0x5Fb9A2b7AE59A85565809044a418CC35eab13c25"
​
gas: 67670
​
gasPrice: "16000000000"
​
hash: "0xaf7bfec2f84b35a58e93ebdf688ba079721b2ac064d7adff520100352206472d"
​
input: "0x23b872dd000000000000000000000000237b64806c7883e778e9b74edde05f903524d6900000000000000000000000005fb9a2b7ae59a85565809044a418cc35eab13c25000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000094cae0664ceabbe800"
​
nonce: 2565
​
r: "0x6dad8ac29469c6ffb0daf5aed64e4351155cbcdd08e180c48404ffed85cd5b03"
​
s: "0x440566bf839a5edf1d506b4829b6cdbefdf1d9f12706b4c78a2de25e01cba022"
​
to: "0x8dd5fbCe2F6a956C3022bA3663759011Dd51e73E"
​
transactionIndex: 12
​
v: "0x25"
​
value: "0"
```